# Discordjs music bot - After some time-- bot abruptly stops playing music, then plays the next song, then stops again, then play-- till the last song

Tags: node.js, youtube, discord.js, bots, audio-player

It is working fine most of the time... but sometimes there's a random moment in which the player stops, then moves to the next song, stops again, and moves on-- till there's no song in queue. It doesn't throw in any error code so I am quite troubled.

Recently it happened in a long video past 1 hour long, but it did happen in shorter 5 min videos as well(I should note that it happened when I used 'YT-search' to queue songs and I suspect it triggered due to lag.)

This is the part where I suspect there to be a problem:

```js
const videoPlayer = async function (message, song) {
  const guild = message.guild;
  const songQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
  
  if(!song) {
      songQueue.connection.disconnect();
      queue.delete(guild.id);
      songDisplay = undefined;
      songList = undefined;
      return message.channel.send("There are no more songs in queue.");
  }
  
  const stream = ytdl(song.url, {
    filter: 'audioonly', 
    highWaterMark: 16384 * song.duration,
    requestOptions: {
      headers: {
        cookie: process.env.COOKIE
      }
    }
  });
  const player = Voice.createAudioPlayer();
  const resource = Voice.createAudioResource(stream);
  await player.play(resource);
  songQueue.connection.subscribe(player);

  songPlayer = player;

  let songDetails = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(song.authorName)
    .setTitle(`Playing \`${song.title}\``)
    .setDescription(`Video Link: ${song.url}\nChannel Link: ${song.authorChannel}`)
    .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail);

  if(songDisplay != undefined) songDisplay.delete();
  message.channel.send('Initializing...')
  .then(display => {
    songDisplay = display;
    songDisplay.edit( { content: null, embeds: [songDetails] } )
  })

  player.on(Voice.AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, async () => {
      songQueue.songs.shift();
      videoPlayer(message, songQueue.songs[0]);
  })
}
```

I wonder if there's a way to monitor the requests being sent? I am new to Nodejs so I don't really understand it much though.

EDIT:
I feel like I know the problem-- I set up too many listener for AudioPlayer... because every time the videoPlayer function is called, a new listener is constructed

So I made it so that they initialize on run instead of in the function, together with the AudioPlayer itself at the top of the code.

Comment: Please don't post all your code.

Comment: Hmm, why? Sorry, I code for a hobby so I don't really know much about what is proper--

Comment: No problem, it's just that it's very hard to find the issue when there is a bunch of code to look at.

Comment: Let me modify it then-- I suspect it might be somewhere in the videoPlayer function

Comment: Alright, sorry im not an expert at discordjs but ill try to find a bug

Comment: There we go-- I'll go try troubleshooting in the meanwhile. Thx a lot